# How to resize image at same position in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

When i resize image with `Shift+arrow down` its position also move . How can I resize without moving original position in Excel ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit like "Doctor, Doctor, when I do this it hurts" - "Well, then don't do this."

Don't use Shift + arrow to resize, then.

Use the mouse and grab the corner opposite of the corner that you want to stay fixed and move that corner.

I.e. if you want the top left corner of the picture to stay where it is, click and drag the bottom right corner.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I know that stuff but you know I am lazy king LOL . anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the position of the picture, but only want to change the size of the picture, you can right-click and select the ***format picture*** and manually change its size, so that only the size of the picture will change.

[image]